# Can change the location of the icon relative to the text in the Tab?

Tags: flutter, tabs

If use Tab with two parameters when building a TabBar, for example:

```
   bottom: TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(icon: Icon(text: "Car", Icons.directions_car)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(text: "Train", Icons.directions_transit)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(text: "Bike", Icons.directions_bike)),
      ],
    ),
```

then the icon will be located above the text. Is it possible to change this location? For example, put an icon to the left or right of or below text?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If both icon and text are provided, the text is displayed below the icon.

Comment: Was my answer not able to solve your problem? @user3161078

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different design other than default.You can design yourself as per your requirement using a child argument.

You can take this as a simple example of placing an icon right to the text.

```
bottom: TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(child:Row(children:[Text('a'), Icon(Icons.directions_transit)])),
])
```